# Managing classes in tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm working on a project that requires the recognition of just people in a video or a live stream from a camera. I'm currently using the tensorflow object recognition API with python, and i've tried different pre-trained models and frozen inference graphs. I want to recognize only people and maybe cars so i don't need my neural network to recognize all 90 classes that come with the frozen inference graphs, based on mobilenet or rcnn, as it seems this slows the process, and 89 of this 90 classes are not needed in my project. Do i have to train my own model or is there a way to modify the inference graphs and the existing models? This is probably a noob question for some of you, but mind that i've worked with tensorflow and machine learning for just one month.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The existing network has a 90 node softmax head.  There is no merit to removing other nodes.  Just get your detections and throw away classes that you don't want.  If you do feel the need to remove other classes from the network itself, then you have to modify `pipeline.config` file and change `NUM_CLASSES: 1` and retrain the network aka fine-tune it.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I want to remove the not needed classes to speed the process of detection, since i need real time recognition and somewhat accurate.I'm not sure if this speeds up the process or not, i just figured that this could reduce the work on the process thus increasing the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Shrinking the last layer to output 1 or two classes is not likely to yield large speed ups. This is because most of the computation is in the intermediate layers. You could shrink the intermediate layers, but this would result in poorer accuracy.

Comment: I am pretty new to object-detection-api. I would like to know where I can get access to this architecture of layers so that I can modify it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to train own model. Let's see in short words some ways how to do.

**OPTION 1**. When you want to apply transfer knowledge as maximum as possible, you can froze the CNN layers. After, you change a quantity of detected classes with dimension of classifier (dense layers). The classifier is the latest part in CNN architecture. Now, you should retrain only classifier.

**OPTION 2**. Assuming, you want to apply transfer knowledge for first layers of CNN (for example, froze first 2-3 CNN layers) and retrain rest of CNN with classifier. After, you change a quantity of detected classes with dimension of classifier. Now, you should retrain rest of CNN layers and classifier.

**OPTION 3**. Assuming, you want to retrain whole CNN with classifier. After, you change a quantity of detected classes with dimension of classifier. Now, you should retrain whole CNN with classifier.

Generally, the **Tensorflow Object Detection API** is a good start for beginners! How to proceed with your problem you can see [here](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/README.md) more detail about whole process and extra explanation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md).