# How to reset classes while retaining class specific weights in TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, transfer-learning

I am currently using the [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and am attempting to fine tune a pre-trained Faster-RCNN from the model zoo. Currently, if I choose a different number of classes to the number used in the original network, it will simply not initialise the weights and biases from the `SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor` as this now has different dimensions from the original `ClassPredictor`. However, as all of the classes I would like to train the network on are classes the original network has been trained to identify, I would like to retain the weights and biases associated with the classes I want to use in `SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor` and prune all the others, rather than simply initialising these values from scratch (similar to the behaviour of [this function](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/api/model_zoo.html#gluoncv.model_zoo.FasterRCNN.reset_class)).

Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about modifying the structure of this layer in the Estimator?

n.b. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50572962/managing-classes-in-tensorflow-object-detection-api) asks a similar thing, and their response is to ignore irrelevant classes from the network output - in this situation, however, I am attempting to fine tune the network and I assume the presence of these redundant classes would complicate the training / evaluation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the classes you would like to train the network on are the ones the network has been trained to identify, you could simply use the network to detect, isn't it?

However, if you have extra classes and you would like to do transfer-learning, you can have as many variables restored from checkpoint as possible by setting:

```
fine_tune_checkpoint_type: 'detection'
load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: True
```

in field `train_config` from the pipeline config file.

**Finally, by looking at the computation graph, it can be seen that the shape of `SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/weights` is dependent on the number of output classes.** 
[image]

Note that in tensorflow you can only restore in variables level, if two variables have different shapes, one can not use one to initialize the other. So in your case the idea of preserving some values of the `weights` variable is not feasible.

Comment: Many thanks for this - the only issue is, if I set `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: True`, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the classes whose weights / biases I want to preserve. Is there a way to specify which checkpoint variables to preserve, if there is a difference in dimensionality?

Comment: Here is how the variables to restore are selected. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/645202b1e62d323d79936eea9452ef3b58084826/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py#L2266  If `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars` is true, it will try to find all variables that exist in the checkpoint and then restore them. But still if you want to specify more finely, you would have to modify this `restore_map` function, e.g. you could filter out some variables from the dict it returns.

Comment: Many thanks for this :) On a similar note, if I wanted to modify the structure of the first few layers of the feature extractor net, might you know where in the repo I should look?

Comment: this folder (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/models) contains all the wrapper classes for different convnets. You can see that they used `slim` module to build these feature extractors. The slim module contains a lot of predefined CNNs like resnet, inception, vgg, alexnet etc. link to `slim`: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets